# how to create table in PHP using PostgreSQL queries?

Tags: php, html, mysql, postgresql

i have some PostgreSQL queries and its output looks like below. now i want to display that output query PHP how to do this? 
my PostgreSQL query is as follows:

```
   $query = 'select
    round(
    100.00 *
    (sum(case when "WELLTYPE"= 'DT' and ("CONC_ARSC" between 0 and 10) then 1 else 0 end))/(sum(case when "WELLTYPE"= 'DT' then 1 else 0 end)),1) "0-10",
    round(
    100.00 *
    (sum(case when "WELLTYPE"= 'DT' and ("CONC_ARSC" between 11 and 50) then 1 else 0 end))/(sum(case when "WELLTYPE"= 'DT' then 1 else 0 end)),1) "11-50",
    round(
    100.00 *
    (sum(case when "WELLTYPE"= 'DT' and ("CONC_ARSC" >50) then 1 else 0 end))/(sum(case when "WELLTYPE"= 'DT' then 1 else 0 end)),1) ">50",
    round(
    100.00 *
    (sum(case when "WELLTYPE"= 'DT' and ("CONC_ARSC" between 0 and 10) then 1 else 0 end))/(sum(case when ("WELLTYPE"= 'DT' or "WELLTYPE"= 'DW' or "WELLTYPE"= 'FT' or "WELLTYPE"= 'ST') and  ("CONC_ARSC" between 0 and 10)then 1 else 0 end)),1) "Total"
    from public."Arsenic_Test"';
```

The output of above PostgreSQL query looks like:

```
 ____________________________________________
 |0_to_10| 11_to_50 | greater_than_50 | Total|
 --------+----------+-----------------+------|
 | 100   |    0.0   |   0.0           | 0.4  |
----------------------------------------------
```

i am very beginer in php so i dont know how to start. i had setup database connection and its working fine. i had created array to create table in web (using php)

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $db_connection =  pg_connect("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=BankeDB user=postgres password=admin");
        echo $db_connection;
    $query = 'select.... (above query) ';
$result = pg_query($db_connection, $query, $POST);
    $result = pg_query($db_connection, $query);
$DT = array('0-10','11-50','>50',total);
    $result = pg_query($db_connection, $query);
                      while ($DT = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
                 echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>$DT[0]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$DT[1]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$DT[2]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$DT[3]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
                 echo "</tr>";
                 }

    echo $result;            
                 pg_close($db);
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried, and any errors you've encountered. Also, an example of the output you desire would be nice.

Comment: i am very beginer in php so i dont know how to start. i had setup database connection and its working fine. i had created array to create table in web (using php)

Comment: @ChristianF i had addes some information what i have done so far. can you please help me to sort it out?

Comment: What's the result of: php <yourscript.php>  ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you could do, is to sit down and read (aloud) to yourself what each individual line of code does. What it actually does, not what you want it to do, mind you.

A quick example of this, is the following line:
`while ($DT = pg_fetch_row ($result)) {`
It states, that for as long as there is any rows left (`while` and `pg_fetch_row()`), then it should fetch the next row of the result set (`pg_fetch_row()`) and store it into the $DT variable. *Overwriting* any previous data stored in that variable (`$DT =`)

Doing this will give you a much better understanding of what your code actually does, enabling you to do some actual programming and not just throwing stuff at it hoping something sticks (works).

Another prerequisite you should work on, is the actual planning of the steps needed to be taken. If you do this before you start to write the code, it'll become a lot easier to write the code. Seeing as you've actually solved most of the problem beforehand, so that you only need to translate the solution from plain (shorthand) English to PHP.
This is done with a technique called "[pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)", and I strongly recommend reading up on it!

That said, I've cleaned your code up a bit and commented on it. To help you get started:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Normally you'll want to remove the connection details from the code you post.
    $db_connection = pg_connect ("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=BankeDB user=postgres password=admin");

    $query = 'select.... (above query) ';

    // Here you're actually running the query three times in a row,
    // overwriting the previous result each time.
    // Also, why "$POST"?
    $result = pg_query ($db_connection, $query, $POST);
    $result = pg_query ($db_connection, $query);
    $result = pg_query ($db_connection, $query);

    // Temporary variable to hold the output, instead of directly (and irreverably) sending it to the browser.
    // Using the HereDOC syntax, to make things a bit easier to read.
    // It's here you want to write out the headers, as they're in their own row. (TR == table row)
    $htmlOut = <<<outHTML
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
outHTML;

    // Why not just add the table header cells to the output directly?
    $DT = array ('0-10', '11-50', '>50', total);

    // As you're overwriting (deleting) the contents of above array here anyway.
    while ($DT = pg_fetch_row ($result)) {
        // Again, hereDOC syntax for easier reading.
        // Though, where do you get the "$row" variable from?
        $htmlOut .= <<<outHTML
        <tr>
            <td>{$DT[0]}</td>
            <td>{$DT[1]}</td>
            <td>{$DT[2]}</td>
            <td>{$DT[3]}</td>
            <td>{$row[4]}</td>
        </tr>
outHTML;
    }

    // $result is a PG resource, so I assume this is for debugging purposes only.
    // echo $result;

    // You'll want to print out the completed array instead.
    echo $htmlOut."\t</tbody>\n</table>\n";
}
```

PS: I also recommend looking into [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), instead of using the old `pg_*()` functions.